# Filter antd Table With datePicker in react

Tags: reactjs, filter, datepicker, ant-design-pro

Following is the code for Ant design table with filtering the object using the input field but i want it to transform it for antd datepicker field instead of input field but not getting how to tranform it.

```js
const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    date: '2020-04-01',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    date: '2020-04-04',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    date: '2020-04-03',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
   date: '2020-04-02',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    searchedColumn: '',
  };

  getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          icon={<SearchOutlined />}
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
          Reset
        </Button>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
      }
    },
    render: text =>
      this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text.toString()}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex,
    });
  };

  handleReset = clearFilters => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: '' });
  };

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Date',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
      },
     
     
    ];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Following is the code for Ant design table with filtering the object using the input field but i want it to transform it for antd datepicker field instead of input field but not getting how to tranform it.

Comment: Any update? Still not able to filter by date range

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this to display a datePicker instead of a searchInput.

```js
<div style={{ padding, width }}>
  <DatePicker.RangePicker
    autoFocus={autoFocus}
    onChange={handleChange}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    value={value}
    format={format}
    style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
  />
  <Button
    type="primary"
    role="search"
    onClick={handleSearch}
    style={{ width: btnWidth }}
    icon={<SearchOutlined />}
    size="small"
  >
    {label[0]}
  </Button>
  <Button
    role="reset"
    style={{ width: btnWidth, marginLeft }}
    onClick={handleClear}
    size="small"
  >
    {label[1]}
  </Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant run code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Old question but hope can help someone in the future!

That code is the one from the table search filter but you should create something like this:

```js
// you need momentjs
import moment from "moment";
// the table data
import data from "../fakeData.js";

class myTable extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    
    state = {
      data: data,
      filteredInfo: null,
      searchTimeText: null,
      searchedTimeColumn: null,
    };
  };
  
  clearFilters = () => {
    this.setState(
      { filteredInfo: null }
    );
  };

  handleTimeRangeSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchTimeText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedTimeColumn: dataIndex,
    });
  };

  handleTimeRangeReset = clearFilters => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({
      searchTimeRange: null,
      searchTimeRangeColumn: null,
    });
  };

  getColumnTimeProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters}) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <DatePicker.RangePicker
          onChange={e => {
            setSelectedKeys(e.length ? [e] : [])
          }}
          placeholder={["Start", "End"]}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          role="search"
          onClick={() => {
            this.handleTimeRangeSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)
          }}
          style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
          icon={<SearchOutlined />}
          size="small"
        >
          Search
        </Button>
        <Button
          role="reset"
          style={{ width: 90 }}
          onClick={() => this.handleTimeRangeReset(clearFilters)}
          size="small"
        >
          Reset
        </Button>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => (
      <FieldTimeOutlined type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) => record[dataIndex] ? moment(record[dataIndex]).isBetween(moment(value[0]), moment(value[1])) : "",
    render: text => text
  });

render() {
  let {
    data,
    filteredInfo
  } = this.state;

  // table columns config
  const columns = [
  //...
  {
     title: 'Date',
     dataIndex: 'date',
     key: 'date',
     sorter: (a, b) => a.date > b.date,
     sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === 'date' && sortedInfo.order,
     ...this.getColumnTimeProps('date'),
     filteredValue: filteredInfo.date || null,
  },
  //...
  ];

  // the table
  return (<Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} />)
  );
}
```